# Simulation of IP Core using ModelSim

Tags: fpga, xilinx, modelsim

I try to use IP core in Xilinx ISE 14.2. When the simulation done with ISim it works fine. Now I need to do the simualtion with ModelSim SE-64 10.7.

1. I compile HDL Simualtion Libraries **Fig.1**.
2. I run the simulation with ModelSim but it give me the error :

   ```
   # Model Technology ModelSim SE-64 vcom 10.7 Compiler 2017.12 Dec  7 2017
   # Start time: 18:17:16 on Sep 03,2020
   # vcom -reportprogress 300 -explicit -93 ipcore_dir/CoreAdder.vhd 
   # -- Loading package STANDARD
   # -- Loading package TEXTIO
   # -- Loading package std_logic_1164
   # -- Compiling entity CoreAdder
   # -- Compiling architecture CoreAdder_a of CoreAdder
   # ** Error: (vcom-11) Could not find xilinxcorelib.c_addsub_v11_0.
   # ** Error (suppressible): ipcore_dir/CoreAdder.vhd(66): (vcom-1195) Cannot find expanded name 
     "xilinxcorelib.c_addsub_v11_0".
   # ** Error: ipcore_dir/CoreAdder.vhd(67): (vcom-1105) Name (indexed name) does not denote an 
   entity name.
   # ** Error: ipcore_dir/CoreAdder.vhd(66): Unknown expanded name.
   # ** Note: ipcore_dir/CoreAdder.vhd(108): VHDL Compiler exiting
   # End time: 18:17:16 on Sep 03,2020, Elapsed time: 0:00:00
   # Errors: 4, Warnings: 0
   # ** Error: C:/modeltech64_10.7/win64/vcom failed.
   # Error in macro ./tb_MYAdder.fdo line 23
   # C:/modeltech64_10.7/win64/vcom failed.
   #     while executing
   # "vcom -explicit  -93 "ipcore_dir/CoreAdder.vhd""
   ```

1. The name of the toplevel is: MYAdder.
2. The name of the testBench is: tb_MYAdder.
3. The name of the ip Core in my project :CoreAdder.

[image: Fig.1]

**Fig.1**

Comment: I've never used it before, but have you tried the other entries in that list: 'regenerate all cores' and 'check all core versions'?

Comment: @Justin I try it but there is no relation with that. After my research:  When   the designs contain IP cores , simulating with a 3rd party simulator the library XilinxCoreLib needs to be compiled. Complie HDL Simulation Libraries do that automatically but there is no results in my case. I need now to do it Manually (I don't know how).